# Macports installed applications no longer showing up

Tags: macos, zsh, macports

I recently migrated my shell over to zsh from bash on my os x computer. I obtained zsh from macports, updated my default shell on os x, and restarted. When I tried to use `port` both shells said they couldn't find port.

Adding /opt/local/bin to both of their paths fixed this issue (which is interested because bash's path never included /opt/local/bin yet those programs always worked). However, the problem that still persists is programs I've installed over macports no longer work. For example: issuing emacs --version gives version 22 instead of version 24 which I installed over macports.

Does anyone know what could have happened and how I could fix this?

Comment: How did you add the path? Does `which -a emacs` show you both versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution to this is to start bash, call `echo $PATH` on it, and then inspect what it contains. Perhaps you never added anything to bash's path yourself, but `/etc/profile` or even `~/.profile` are doing that.

Notice that the directory order in your `$PATH` matters. If there are 2 emacs installed, the first one found will be picked up. If `which -a emacs` returns multiple locations, you already have all paths you need, but you probably just placed at the end of `$PATH`. You should place it in the beginning.

Comment: This was exactly my problem. I had `PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin` when I wanted `PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH`. So it was finding the out of date version of emacs first. Thank you.